# How to tell if $query_var isset?

Tags: query, php, variables

I tired to use `isset($queryvar)` but that didnt work, so I implemented my own function `qv_isset`, but it runs into a problem when `$ch` is set to 0.

```
$cls = get_query_var('cls');
$ch = get_query_var('ch');

function qv_isset($var) {
    if($var == '') { return false; 
    } else { return true; }
}

if(qv_isset($cls) && qv_isset($ch)) {
    mcs_textbook_chapter($dialect, $cls, $ch);
} elseif(qv_isset($cls)) {              
    mcs_textbook_chapter($dialect, $cls);
} else {
    mcs_textbook($dialect);
}
```

Comment: Right, it's not trivial to properly check whether or not a query var has been set. I've provided a patch for wordpress which should make that more easy, probably this gets some traction: [Ticket #16471](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16471).

Answer (score 8):

use the [indentical](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) comparison operator:

```
if(get_query_var('cls') !== '' && get_query_var('ch') !== '') {
    mcs_textbook_chapter($dialect, $cls, $ch);
} elseif(get_query_var('cls') !== '') {              
    mcs_textbook_chapter($dialect, $cls);
} else {
    mcs_textbook($dialect);
}
```

Comment: That works too.

Comment: Even if it works, it does not sound to be efficient approach...

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to know wether a *WordPress Query Var* is set or not, you need to check directly for it.

All set query vars are stored into a global accessible array of the WP_Query class.

It has a default instance that is bound to the global  `$wp_query` variable. With that in mind it is possible to create a `qv_isset()` function that is working precicesly:

```
function qv_isset($var_name) {
    $array = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query_vars;
    return array_key_exists($var_name, $array);
}
```

What makes this so easy is that [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) returns true or false.

Normally to test any PHP variable if it is set or not, you can use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). But it has a shortcoming: If a variable is `NULL`, it will say that it is not set - even if it is. Comparable to what has been written about [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) here as well, it will say comparably for `''` (empty string), `NULL`, `0` etc. .

Anyway, we do not need to rely on that function to check wether or not a *queryvar* has been set as we can make use of array_key_exists() here.

---

Now for your code:

```
function qv_get($var_name, $default = null) {
    return qv_isset($var_name) ? get_query_var($var_name) : $default;
}

mcs_textbook_chapter($dialect, qv_get('cls'), qv_get('ch'));
```

Or with other words: If your function already has (that many) optional parameters, take a look how you can best feed it. Unset variables are `NULL` (like said above with isset()), so this is useful to pass them as unset optional parameters as well.

Answer (score 3):

Hi **@imHavoc:**

I might write that code like this *(although there are several valid ways to write it):*

```
$cls = get_query_var('cls');
$ch =  get_query_var('ch');

if (strlen("{$cls}{$ch}")==0) {
  mcs_textbook($dialect);
} if (strlen($ch)==0) {
  mcs_textbook_chapter($dialect, $cls);
} else {
  mcs_textbook_chapter($dialect, $cls, $ch);
}
```

Comment: when `$ch = 0;` the thing fires off, but `echo $ch` displays nothing.

Comment: @imHavoc - I'm confused, how does `echo $ch` relate to your question or the example in my answer?

Comment: @Mike - Sorry for the confusion, let me explain. `echo $ch` is just being used to debug, to find out what is being passed on to the function. When `$ch = 0;`, `echo $ch;` returns nothing, so nothing is passed onto the function.

Comment: @imHavoc - What I am confused by is how you know that `$ch = 0` if `echo $ch;` displays nothing? it would seem that would be impossible so I am expecting you are assuming something that I am not aware of.

Comment: Sorry. I have a rewrite in place that rewrites this `../textbook/cantonese/CK1/0/` as `../textbook/cantonese/index.php?cls=CK1&ch=0`.

Comment: @imHavoc - Ah, that is *completely different* from saying `ch = 0;` is true. :) Have you defined `'ch'` as a valid query argument using `$GLOBALS['wp']->add_query_var('ch')` in an `'init'` hook?  Also, I'd really recommend longer, more descriptive names than `cls` and `ch` if for no other reason than longer more descriptive names are less likely to conflict with names people set in plugins because most plugin vendors do not follow best practices.

Comment: @imHavoc - Did my last comment solve your question?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use **empty**, isset failed because you just set the variable. An empty value is still a value.

```
if ( empty($cls) && empty($ch) ){
    // Not set
}
```

Comment: I read up on the `empty()` function and found out `0` is considered to be empty. How would I instead be able to use `0` in the link: `http://localhost/wordpress/textbook/cantonese/CK1/0/` `cantonese/cls/ch/`

Comment: @imHavoc - I've posted an answer that takes care of the shortcomings of empty.